# Increase persistent Casper RW file

Tags: xubuntu, live-usb, gparted, persistence

Completely new to Linux, decided to install Xubuntu onto a usb using the universal usb installer. I have a 64gb usb stick. I set everything up, booted into live - persistent and everything seemed alright until I decided to install some basic programs. I quickly realized that 4gb persistent file would not be enough. I decided to try and resize my partitions and the only one I can see is my fat32 partition I cannot unmount it because 'the CD ROM is busy'. How do I increase the size of my Casper -rw file (File or partition because I can't see it in gparted or fdisk -l?) Or is there any way to create a persistent partition and resize my current one? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in  advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is not possible to make a casper-rw file greater than 4GB because of a limitation of FAT32, however, it is not difficult to make a casper-rw partition.

Note: You may want to backup your data before you start doing this, data can always be lost while partitioning, copying, etc.

This is outlined in Method 0 of https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent

You'll have to make use another live USB in order to resize the partition. After you've booted into the other live USB,

1. Open `gparted`
2. Resize the FAT32 partition of the original USB drive to almost as small as it can be
3. Make a new ext4 partition named "casper-rw" (without the quotes)
4. Click "apply"

Now you just have to copy the data over

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/casper-rw of=/dev/sdX
```

Where sdX is the new partition you created (also add "status=progress" if you're impatient and want to see the progress like me)

After it's done copying, delete the original casper-rw file and it should be good to go.

Comment: Could I use a live CD instead of a second live usb? (Thanks for the answer!)

Comment: Yes, a live CD should do as well

Comment: any particular reason to use `dd` instead of  `cp`?

Comment: cp is to copy files, dd will copy binary data of the partition, and that may matter. the format of casper-rw is difftent than ext4 it's just ext4 is a container for casper-rw file